# df2.loc['average']= df2.mean() gives NaN row?

Tags: python, dataframe

The first line is working well. In the second line is giving me `NaN` when it should be the average of each column?

```
df2.sort_values(by=['All'], ascending=[False], inplace=True)
df2.loc['average']= df2.mean()
print(df2)
```

This is what I get

```
          Accuracy                           All  ...    CUpDn   TRND
3        Random Forest                     83.06  ...    67.65  72.02
5        Linear Logistic Regression        79.13  ...    59.34  73.01
9        MLP                               77.16  ...    60.87  73.55
0        Decision Tree                      75.3  ...    54.32  66.56
2        SVM                               73.55  ...    59.45  73.22
8        Quadratic Discriminan Analysis    73.55  ...     63.5  66.99
1        KNeighbors                        71.58  ...    67.21  65.25
7        AdaBoost                          59.34  ...    60.33  59.34
6        SGD                               48.74  ...    50.27  67.54
4        GaussianNB                        48.52  ...    44.37   69.4
average                               NaN    NaN  ...      NaN    NaN
```

df2.dtypes shows:

```
Classifier Accuracy                           object
All                                           object
 5D                                           object
10D                                           object
15D                                           object
20D                                           object
50D                                           object
100D                                          object
200D                                          object
Chg%                                          object
MA                                            object
MAX                                           object
MIN                                           object
MM%                                           object
CUpDn                                         object
TRND                                          object
dtype: object
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you include the output of `df2.dtypes`?

Comment: Classifier Accuracy object All object 5D object 10D object 15D object 20D object 50D object 100D object 200D object Chg% object MA object MAX object MIN object MM% object CUpDn object TRND object dtype: object

Comment: That's the problem, your data is stored as strings rather than numbers. Try `df2[df2.columns[1:]] = df2[df2.columns[1:]].astype(float)`. You might get an error if there's data that can't be converted to float, which would be the reason they got loaded that way in the first place.

Comment: Perfect! you're a genius!..that worked..thanks...1 last thing..so the row now has the averages which is great...but the first column which should contain the word 'Average' shows Nan...I know I can fix this by using df2.iloc[-1,0]='Average' but is there a more efficient way to do it in one step?  df2.loc['average']= df2.mean()
It seems that the command puts the word 'average' in the index column instead of the first column. Thanks so much for your help :-)

Comment: My code skipped the first column because it contained the names. I think a cleaner approach to your problem would be to set that column as the index, I'm not sure what its called, let's say classifier. So you could do: `df2.set_index('classifier', inplace=True); df2 = df2.astype(float); df2.loc['average'] = df2.mean()`

Comment: Another great advice!. You've solved my problem. I'm very grateful, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what solved my problem:

"That's the problem, your data is stored as strings rather than numbers. Try:

```py
df2[df2.columns[1:]] = df2[df2.columns[1:]].astype(float)
```

You might get an error if there's data that can't be converted to float, which would be the reason they got loaded that way in the first place. – josemz 1 hour ago"